# Change Background Picture with scripting

Tags: rendering, scripting

[image]
i tried to change the background of my blender scene in a python script.
I changed the background manually. These were the following commands in console:

```
bpy.context.space_data.context = 'WORLD'

bpy.ops.image.open(filepath="//mount_02.jpg", directory="E:\\bs_ba\\ml-tensorflow\\", 
files=`[{"name":"mount_02.jpg", "name":"mount_02.jpg"}], show_multiview=False)`
```

I wrote the same commands in a script. There was no error, but it didn´t do anything.
Any ideas how i can change the background for rendering in my scene with scripting?
I added a picture of my current scene.